# Can I use a membership custom field in a renewal confirmation e-mail

Tags: civimember, custom-fields, renewals

I use a custom field in my membership records (Reference code). This custom field {membership.custom_8} i can use in e-mail reminders of the type membership that i use to warn members about an expiring membership. This works fine.

When i renew a membership i want to send a confirmation e-mail to confirm the renewal. To accomplish this i created a reminder of the type Activity. In the e-mail template i would like to use the custom field mentioned before. The e-mail is sent okay but now the custom field is not displayed.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you could see what civitoken extension might do for you

Comment: Do you mean Fuzion Tokens? I'm already using this extension but as far as i see custom fields are not handled by this extension.

Comment: ok so the issue of course if folk can have multiple memberships, so if you are starting from a 'contact' there is no automatic logic as to which custom-membership field to go an grab. if it is always going to be latest_membership then it may be possible to create such a token (that is generic) and add to the above extension - otherwise you might find a custom solution/extension the quickest way to get what you need. Ping us if you would like some professional support. otherwise we will do what we can to provide community (free) support via this thread if you have some dev skills to get going